# Sending a BIT to Entity Framework, but EF sees an INT

Tags: sql, entity-framework

I am doing the following within a SQL function:

```
SELECT
    c.DateValue,
    c.DayName,
    c.IsPaymentDate,
    CAST(CASE WHEN exception.ExceptionDateId IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS BIT) AS IsHolidayPayment,
    exception.ExceptionDateID
FROM Calendar c
```

However, when opening the model in Entity Framework, it sees the IsHolidayPayment as an INT. We need it to be a Boolean. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: is this code first or edmx?

Comment: edmx, generated from database.

Comment: The framework should be interpreting sql bit types to bool in .net. If you go in your EF designer you should be able to change the column type from int to bool from a drop down list in the properties window for that table.

Comment: I agree with Nick. The framework should be interpreting bit types as bool automatically. If you have changed the column type after generating the EDMX than you need to update the EDMX again using the "Update from Database" option.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if the field has been modified after EDMX generated then we have to update the field manually,
after changing the still i faced some problem, as it also generated complex data type if stored procedure returns some rows
so better approach i follow if possible , i delete this stored procedure ,and update edmx again and re-add it

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I came across it so other people might as well. As a workaround, I created a BIT variable and then set the column to that variable. Entity framework was able to then identify that the column is a boolean.

```
DECLARE @IsBitVariable BIT = 0

SELECT
    c.DateValue,
    c.DayName,
    c.IsPaymentDate,
    @IsBitVariable AS IsHolidayPayment,
    exception.ExceptionDateID
FROM Calendar c
```

Save the data model and then change your query back.